# How to change text color for GRUB2 menu in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: grub2

How do I change the text color for the GRUB2 menu in Ubuntu 20.04 on a desktop with both Ubuntu and Windows 10?  I have tried different solutions that I read online, but nothing works.  I was able to change it briefly with the grub command line, but the result was only temporary as expected.

Comment: I found an article that works by editing a theme file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grub-customizer` to do that. You will find a install guide here: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-grub-customizer-on-linux-all-major-distros